# .htaccess rewrite part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite/remove part of old url whit htaccess.

old url:

```
/event/seometxt.15.html?id=14&utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=mypage
```

new url:

```
/event/seometxt/?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=mypage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as first rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?id=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(event/[^.]+)\. /$1/?%1%2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# rest of your rules go here
```